# Set `selected text` through the macOS Accessibility APIs in Catalyst apps

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, mac-catalyst

Not sure if it's a bug or what. I made an app that add Vim bindings all over macOS, but it fails in Catalyst apps. The text is readable mostly—although line numbers are wrong and line ranges too—but I can't set the selected text. It does nothing expect selecting the text, but not replacing it with the new one. It works well in all native apps that support the Accessibility.

Am I doing things wrong or is this a confirmed bug? (I've been reporting bugs in the Accessibility API for two years, with no change from Apple's part.)

The code is fairly simple. As an example:

```swift
func ....() {
    var selectedTextRange = CFRange()
    selectedTextRange.location = 2
    selectedTextRange.length = 3
        
    let newValue = AXValueCreate(.cfRange, &selectedTextRange)
    guard AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(axFocusedElement, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute as CFString, newValue!) == .success else { return false }
        
    guard AXUIElementSetAttributeValue(axFocusedElement, kAXSelectedTextAttribute as CFString, "hehe" as CFTypeRef) == .success else { return false }
       
    return true
}
```

The func returns true. But in Catalyst apps there's a selection from location 2 to 5, but the text is not replaced by "hehe".

I've got an Xcode project also that shows the issue: https://github.com/godbout/AXBugsWithCatalystApps

Thanks.